# what is the role of timer here

Tags: c#, timer

here the code what is the actual role of timer,,other thing is which if(saving) will trigger first ,if modification not happened means server fail..Is there any relation with thread..

```
private void Dlg_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Set the message.
    if (Saving)
        eLabel.Text = Managers.ControlStrings.GetString("Saving");


    // Setup to receive events.
    Server.InfoReceived += new InfoEventHandler(Server_InfoReceived);
    Server.Received += new ServerStateEventHandler(Server_ServerStateReceived);

    // Start the timer to begin saving as soon as the dialog has completed setup.
    Timer.Start();
}

/// Handle the tick of the timer by stopping the timer and beginning the operation.  This allows
/// the dialog to come up fully before the operation is started; otherwise there are problems
/// closing the dialog.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Timer.</param>
/// <param name="e">Ignored.</param>
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string func = "Dlg.Timer_Tick";
    try
    {
        // Stop timer
        Timer.Stop();

        if (Saving)


            if (!Server.Modify())
            {

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't mean to be an ass, but can you go back to your question and revise to use complete sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the comments in the code.

It is to wait for everything to be drawn correctly before doing the action in the timer event.
`Application.DoEvents()` is sometimes used for similar "waiting".

I guess that the timer interval is 1 millisecond.

Comment: well, it's a hacky pattern to deffer execution until the form is completely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The only clue we have here is the XML comment:

```
/// Handle the tick of the timer by stopping the timer and beginning the operation.  
/// This allows the dialog to come up fully before the operation is started; 
/// otherwise there are problems closing the dialog.
```

Apparently there is a problem with the sequence of initialization. It smells a bit like a hack, but we don't see enough code to decide what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

it's look like it is a bad way to wait for a dialog to be display in order (saving?) to do something when the dialog is displayed.